# SQL query issue, error on join expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the query below that is causing the following error:

> ERROR 3296 (Access)
>
> The ON statment in your Join operation is incomplete or contains too many tables. You may want to put the ON expression in a WHERE clause

```sql
SELECT
    TBLCATB.Markis AS [Account #], TBLCATB.[Group Number],
    Max(TBLCATB.Name) AS [Account Name], Sum(TBLCATB.Current) AS [Current],
    Sum(TBLCATB.Thirty) AS Thirty, Sum(TBLCATB.Sixty) AS Sixty,
    Sum(TBLCATB.Ninety) AS Ninety, Max(TBLCATB.[Company Code]) AS [Company Code]
FROM
    TBLCATB
    LEFT JOIN asc_OracleMarkis
        ON CLng(TBLCATB.Markis)=asc_OracleMarkis.Markis
WHERE
    (((TBLCATB.LOB) Like "g*" Or (TBLCATB.LOB) Like "l*" Or
      (TBLCATB.LOB) Like "pb*")) AND
    CLng(tblcatb.markis) not in (select acctnumber from sb_acctinfo)
GROUP BY
    TBLCATB.Markis, TBLCATB.[Group Number]
HAVING
    (((Sum(TBLCATB.Ninety))<>0))
ORDER BY
    Sum(TBLCATB.Ninety) DESC;
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: What is the error?  What is the database?  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi there & welcome. Gordon is right, you lack some info here.

Comment: you are gonna laugh, but its a legacy access database. I migrated some of the tables to SQL Server and now it doesn't like the join.  INNER JOIN works oddly enough but the LEFT JOIN doesnt.

Comment: @Melvin, what would you need to know?  The exact error is ERROR 3296 in MS ACCESS "The ON statment in your Join operation is incomplete or contains too many tables. You may want to put the ON expression in a WHERE clause"

Comment: Why do you need `LEFT JOIN asc_OracleMarkis`?

Comment: @HansUp because there are cases where an inner join would not give me all results.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I meant why do you need `asc_OracleMarkis` at all, regardless of join type?  The query does not reference any fields from that table except in the `ON` clause.

Comment: @HansUp because the data in TBLCATB has to have a match in asc_OracleMarkis to be shown, the reason its not an INNER JOIN is because sometimes that asc_OracleMarkis table is not up to date and I still need records from tblCATB

Comment: Then with a `LEFT JOIN`, a row from `TBLCATB` will be shown whether or not a match exists in `asc_OracleMarkis`.  In that case, what good does it do to join `asc_OracleMarkis` at all?

Comment: @HansUp yes thats correct and thats what the additional filtering covers, the like "g" etc.

Comment: The `WHERE` filtering conditions are all based on `TBLCATB` ... `asc_OracleMarkis` is not involved in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like MS Access syntax and you are missing a closing parantheses:

```
SELECT TBLCATB.Markis AS [Account #], 
    TBLCATB.[Group Number], 
    Max(TBLCATB.Name) AS [Account Name], 
    Sum(TBLCATB.Current) AS [Current], 
    Sum(TBLCATB.Thirty) AS Thirty, 
    Sum(TBLCATB.Sixty) AS Sixty, 
    Sum(TBLCATB.Ninety) AS Ninety, 
    Max(TBLCATB.[Company Code]) AS [Company Code]
FROM TBLCATB 
LEFT JOIN asc_OracleMarkis 
    ON CLng(TBLCATB.Markis)=asc_OracleMarkis.Markis
WHERE 
(
    (TBLCATB.LOB Like "g*" Or TBLCATB.LOB Like "l*" Or TBLCATB.LOB Like "pb*") 
    AND CLng(tblcatb.markis) not in (select acctnumber from sb_acctinfo)
) <-- this is missing
GROUP BY TBLCATB.Markis, TBLCATB.[Group Number]
HAVING Sum(TBLCATB.Ninety)<>0
ORDER BY Sum(TBLCATB.Ninety) DESC;
```

Comment: When I add that ')' it now says "Extra ) in query expression

Comment: @user1949586 see my edit, I stripped all the unneeded `)`'s from the query.

Comment: @bluefeet, thanks still getting the Join is not supported error.  The query works in SSMS but stupid Access doesnt like the LEFT JOIN Anymore.  Was working fine until I migrated the table.

Comment: @user1949586 What happens if you remove the `CLng()` from the join?

Comment: Ok, if you `SELECT *` from your tables, no aggregates or `WHERE` does the query work?

Comment: Yes, formatting the query and stripping superfluous parentheses  makes it more readable and revelas the error.

Comment: @user1949586 Do you need the `LEFT JOIN` you are not using any of the data from that table?

Comment: @bluefeet I believe the LEFT JOIN is necessary because there could be cases where the INNER JOIN would not give me all results needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Clng trying either using CAST or CONVERT

Comment: SQL is a generic tag, the particular flavour is MS Access. Cast and Convert are not available in MS Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In case your table is a SQL-Server table. Make your query a Pass-Through query and write it in TSQL syntax.

See: [pass through query access sql server](http://www.google.com/search?q=pass+through+query+access+sql+server)